# Freemarker передача null

Tags: java, freemarker

У меня в шаблоне freemarker есть переменная ${datetime}
Передаю в неё null. 
Получаю ошибку

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
```

Смысл то ясен, все же передаю null.

Но условие вроде этого <#if datetime == null> тоже выдает ошибку.

Как мне в freemarker написать условие, что если null, то одно действие иначе - другое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел решение на свой вопрос.

Если нужно сделать проверку на null или missing, то достаточно в шаблоне 
freemarker сделать след. проверку `<#if datetime??>`.

То есть два знака вопроса служат для данной проверки

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно так пишу условие

```
<#if date == null>${date?date("dd.MM.yyyy")?date} <#else> другое действие </#if>
```